# Send files from One server to another.

Tags: php

I have large files (total ~250mb) on my web server. I want to send these files quickly to my 2nd server without using an ftp client. I know the ftp password, username etc of my 2nd server, but how to do it without an ftp client?

Comment: Is PHP required? Cannot `wget` be used from target server to just download the files? (just asking, as anyway - sending big files from php to php can result in fail - slow speed, memory limits..)

Comment: Does my solution below satisfy your question? If so, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = 'somehugefile.big';
 $remote_file = '/uploads/somehugefile.big';

// set up basic connection
 $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
 $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
 if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
  echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
  echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
 ftp_close($conn_id);
```

This example is adapted from the official docs -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

You will have to change 'upload_max_filesize' and 'post_max_size' in PHP.ini to a higher value as well.

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '250M');     
ini_set('max_execution_time', '999');
ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '250M');
```

Comment: Just remember  `FTP_BINARY` not the FTP_ASCII or non-text files would be broken!

Comment: My pleasure. But changing that limits is BAD anyway. You can write your own simple protocol and split big files into smaller ones.. Then send the small ones through php-ftp and the join them together on target server.

Comment: @Seti, Why is changing the limit Bad? Surely it will be fine for the OP's needs though.

Comment: Its changing limit for ALL requests. The main reason for them being small is that many requests can be done at once and servers have limited memory amount anyway.  If he immediately after finishing the sending return them back to normal and restarts the server its OK. If not... then that can be a HUGE problem later. (Like infinity loop with 100% usage - normally broken by time limit after 30 sec, now after 999 sec... also it can now consume 500mb before getting killed. And so on.

Comment: And also not all settings can be changed by `ini_set` some must be changed by php.ini file (and i dont think he can change them just grom php execution - he will need (probably) to change them for all - not just for this execution). Thats why its usually bad.

Comment: @Seti, that would be a problem. How would I allow uploads of a larger size if I am running a cloud storage service?

Comment: I dont know exactly what storage you are suing - but i would keep the files in parts. If the storage have its API - maybe it even allows to send the files into it chunked.